# Mount only a part of a disk to a folder

Tags: mount, fstab

Hi have the following problem.

I have a disk `/dev/sda1` mounted on `/`. The same disk contains a `/home` directory and I want to mount only that directory on a `/backup` mount-point because I have a third party script that require to read data in `/backup`

In the `/etc/fstab` the string that mount the disk to the root `/` is the following:

```
UUID=a72d084b-4bd2-4f05-a223-4e94ca2349aa / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0  1
```

I think it does not make sense to mount a subfolder of a disk to another folder inside the same disk and that a symlink should do the work, but is there a way to do this with `mount`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use "mount --bind" to meet your requirements.
for example:

```
sudo mkdir /media/bin
sudo mount --bind /bin /media/bin
```

In your case:

```
sudo mkdir /backup
sudo mount --bind /home /backup
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the `mount --bind` permanent like to what is done in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: You may look here for this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/613179/how-do-i-do-mount-bind-in-etc-fstab
I would recommend to use /etc/fstab only for system critical file systems. for all others use startup-scripts (systemd or initd) to avoid a hanging system during boot.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any tutorial where the correct usage of remote mounts of folders is described through startup scripts? I already had the problems of frozen fstab because the ip address of a server changed...